# Why do I need an assessor instead of getting directly my value from my binded object data property

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding

I don't  get something, I have this class :

```
public class User : BindableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...
    [JsonIgnore]
    public static readonly BindableProperty PseudoProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Pseudo), typeof(string), typeof(User), "");

    public string Pseudo
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PseudoProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PseudoProperty, value); }
    }
    // ...
}
```

which is declared in the C# part like that :

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Current user property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty CurrentuserProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CurrentUser), typeof(User), typeof(MapPage), User.GetUserInstance());

    /// <summary>
    /// Current user accessor
    /// </summary>
    private User CurrentUser
    {
        get { return (User)GetValue(CurrentuserProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentuserProperty, value); }
    }

    // ...

    public MapPage()
    {
        base.BindingContext = this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

If I want to display the `Pseudo` property in the XAML, I saw on internet that I can do like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding CurrentUser.Pseudo}"/>
```

However, it doesn't work..

---

The weird thing is  that I can display the `Pseudo` in the XAML  side if I create an assessor in the C# side:

```
public string UserPseudo { get { return CurrentUser.Pseudo; } }
```

I then bind my value like it:

```
<Label Text="{Binding UserPseudo}"/>
```

Can someone explain me the logic, because I'm really not sure to understand why do I need an assessor instead of just binding directly my label's value and my object's property value?

Thank for help..

Comment: I took a look but, I'm not sure to understand the link you gave since my value isn't static .. Look again my code and his code ;)

Comment: What is your page's DataContext set to?

Comment: In the constructor, I just edited the post :)

Comment: Sorry, wrong reading :( Too tired after job, time to stop reviewing questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all boils down to the DataContext of the control. The DataContext is also inherited from the control's parent if it is not explicitly set.

```
<Label Text="{Binding CurrentUser.Pseudo}"/>
```

The above works if your `DataContext` is an object that has a property `CurrentUser`.

If your `DataContext` is a `CurrentUser` then you do

```
<Label Text="{Binding Pseudo}"/>
```

So say you wanted a big section of controls based on your `CurrentUser` property.

You may have something like:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentUser.Psuedo}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentUser.FirstName}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentUser.LastName}" />
</StackPanel>
```

But if you set the `DataContext`, you could have it like this:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding CurrentUser}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Psuedo}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
</StackPanel>
```

## EDIT: D'OH!!

The problem you are actually having is because your original property is `private`. It needs to be public in order for XAML to see it. Change your

```
private User CurrentUser...
```

to be

```
public User CurrentUser...
```

Comment: Ok thank but, how can I change the DataContext of just a bit of code? Sorry, but I'm not sure to understand .. :/

Comment: I don't follow. Every control has a property `DataContext` that you can bind to. I'll try to put an example of what I think you are asking for.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, I feel stupid honestly.. thank for the explaination

Comment: Dammmm just because it's private ! :O I don't even need the `DataContext`. Also, I tried to add the `DataContext="{Binding CurrentUser}"` to my `<AbsoluteLayout/>` but it throws an exception that says it's not correct/valid, but Thank you so much :)

Comment: Plus, I don't need a such complicated user class, if I only put `public string foo { get; set; }`, it's enough, I don't need the `BindableProperty` part

Comment: @Emixam23 `DataContext` is a WPF thing. In Xamarin Forms it is called the `BindingContext`. Also most of the time for models you will use a regular getter and setter property but for custom controls you might use a bindable property.

Comment: 2nd answer fail... I didn't even notice the Xamarin. My mind locked on to XAML and assumed WPF.